# Inlining private methods in C++

Tags: c++, inline

In every example I've seen the keyword `inline` is used for public class methods(or functions) in header files.

Is anything special about inlining a **private** class method in the implementation file?

Comment: No, there isn't. `inline` is orthogonal to access specifiers.

Comment: Only that inlining makes the *implementation* less private to readers.  But that's a different kind of "private".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing special in private function being inline, also any function that defined inside class declaration becomes implicitly inline.